# Hosting Golang Application on Cpanel

Tags: go, web, hosting, cpanel, web-hosting

I've developed a golang web application using the gin gonic framework.
Im using shared hosting and control everything over my the cPanel.
I uploaded the compiled go app and launched it using a custom certificate.

When launching the application I get
 `[GIN-debug] Listening and serving HTTPS on :3000`

Although when I try to visit the website with my domain_name:port it doesn't work. It just keeps loading forever and nothing happens. Is there any way I can redirect port 80 or 443 to my golang application if that makes sense?

Answer (score 0):

In your Go app you should be able to chose what port your app is listening on:

`router.Run("localhost:443")`

Comment: then how do I make a request? I always get a blocked message due to it's a http not https, and I can't access my https://ip:port because it's a shared cpanel hosting

Comment: If your app is running on port 443, you will need to configure https from cPanel, which will require getting a cert. If your running it on http (port 80) then you can by pass the browser block. In chrome you just click a blank section and type “thisisunsafe” and it will let you see http pages